# Lookup for matching filed and swap two column for matching lines in two files

Tags: awk

I am having two files. Number of lines in File1 is more than File2. Bellow is a small representation of the files. I want to compare the column1 of both the files and if they matches I want to print the line from File1; replacing the column10 and column11 of File1 with File2

While trying the following command its printing lines without matching also.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {s[$1]=$10; q[$1]=$11; next} $1 in s { $10=s[$1]; $11=q[$1]}1' File2 File1
```

File1

```
1_223022/4194397/c  4   *   0   255 *   *   0   0   zvt 443 np:i:79 rs:B:i,79,0,0,0,80,0    sn:B:f,7.14491,13.3994,7.52773,12.8957  za:f:0  zs:B:f,0
1_223022/4194398/c  4   *   0   255 *   *   0   0   tty 221 np:i:92 rs:B:i,94,0,0,0,0,0 sn:B:f,6.0494,11.9021,5.88262,10.3733   za:f:0  zs:B:f,0
411_223022/4194426/v    4   *   0   255 *   *   0   0   gvy 721 np:i:17 rs:B:i,19,0,0,0,1,0 sn:B:f,7.48538,14.1506,7.67945,13.5199  za:f:0  zs:B:f,0
```

File2

```
1_223022/4194397/c  4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   vtg 235 MT
1_223022/4194398/c  4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   aat 999 SO
```

Expected Output

```
1_223022/4194397/c  4   *   0   255 *   *   0   0   vtg 235 np:i:79 rs:B:i,79,0,0,0,80,0    sn:B:f,7.14491,13.3994,7.52773,12.8957  za:f:0  zs:B:f,0
1_223022/4194398/c  4   *   0   255 *   *   0   0   aat 999 np:i:92 rs:B:i,94,0,0,0,0,0 sn:B:f,6.0494,11.9021,5.88262,10.3733   za:f:0  zs:B:f,0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the end of your command:

```
}1
```

The `1` will always evaluate to true, which makes awk print every line

Instead it should be:

```
 ... $1 in s { $10=s[$1]; $11=q[$1];print}
```

---

Reminder:

`awk` programs consist of a sequence of

```
CONDITION { Block of actions } [; CONDITION { Block of actions } ; ... ]
```

where either the condition or the block of actions is optional: If the condition is missing, awk will always execute the block of actions, if the block of actions is missing, awk will use `print` as the default action if the condition evaluates to true.

```
1
```

is an always-true condition with no actions. This means that awk will print the line.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$10;b[$1]=$11;next} ($1 in a){$10=a[$1];$11=b[$1];print}'  file2  file1
```

Add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in case your Input_files are tab delimited and you need output in tab delimited form too.